# Почему автоматически не заполняется внешний ключ, если задан первичный?

Tags: mysql

Создаю таблицы следующим образом.

```
CREATE TABLE photo (
    photo_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    photo_url VARCHAR(200)
);

CREATE TABLE article (
    date int,
    text VARCHAR(500),
    photo_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY (photo_id) REFERENCES photo(photo_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

При заполнении таблиц в столбце photo_id поля остаются NULL. Почему не происходит автозаполнение?

Comment: Вы не указали для поля `photo.photo_id` свойство `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: После указания свойства `AUTO_INCREMENT` у `photo.photo_id` в столбце `article.photo_id` значения по прежнему `NULL`

Comment: Что-то непонятно.. вы вставляете запись в `photo` и ожидаете что что-то добавится и в `article` ? А с какой стати?

Comment: Видимо я не до конца понял тему о первичных и внешних ключах.  Начал изучать SQL неделю назад. Поэтому прошу простить за ламерские вопросы.

Comment: Вам запись в `article` в любом случае надо добавлять. А вот специальные дополнения `ON DELETE/ON UPDATE  CASCADE/RESTRICT/SET NULL/NO ACTION` позволяют например удалить записи из дочерней таблицы если была удалена из родительской или например если изменился `id` в родительской то автоматом изменится `id` и в дочерней....... но вот автозаполнение...что-то такого не припомню............ либо я что-то не всё понял из вопроса))

Comment: Спасибо. Получается, если в `photo` первичный ключ `photo_id` и каждому его значению принадлежит `photo_url`, то обращаясь к `article` по вторичному `photo_id` я смогу получить `photo_url` без явного обращения к таблице `photo`? Вот так стал понимать связь.

Comment: Нет, без явного обращения не сможете. Но БД будет следить, чтобы значения `photo_id` в таблице `article` соответствовали одному из значений `photo_id` в таблице `photo`.